# custom default styles have been removed by PurgeCSS in nuxt-tailwindcss

Tags: nuxt.js, tailwind-css, css-purge

In my SSR Nuxt.js project, I am using Nuxt offical [tailwindcss-module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/tailwindcss-module)

I coded a default style for `<a></a>` tags like below.

**/assets/scss/app.scss**

```
a{
    color: color("blue", "base");
    transition: color .3s ease;

    &:hover,&:active{
        color: color("blue", "darken-4");
    }
}
```

**pages/index.vue**

```js
<template>
    <nuxt-link to="/login">Login</nuxt-link>
</template>
```

**nuxt.config.js**

```js
    buildModules:['@nuxtjs/tailwindcss'],
    css:['@/assets/scss/app.scss']
```

When I run `npm run dev`, the PurgeCSS would not work, so the result is what I expected.

But when I run `npm run prod`, the PurgeCSS of tailwindcss will remove my own style for `<a></a>` tags in **'@/assets/scss/app.scss'**

How can I config `tailwind.config.js` to make custom default styles be rendered in result? Whitelist only accepts classnames/ids.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
/* purgecss start ignore */
a {...}
/* purgecss end ignore */
```